# Consolidar arquivos .csv com Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Boa Noite,
por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar com a dúvida abaixo?

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que leia todos os csv's com o mesmo conteúdo de uma pasta e os consolide em um único arquivo, desconsiderando a primeira linha, porém ao executar o código abaixo o arquivo final não possuí dados um embaixo do outro e sim um ao lado do outro, como posso corrigir?

Arquivo final:
Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor,Data,Nome,Valor
01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1,01/01/2020,Teste,1

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    diretorio = "C:/Users...{}"
    consolidado = []
    
    for i in lista_arquivos:
        consolidado.append(pd.read_csv(diretorio.format(i), sep=';'))

arq_consolidado = pd.concat(consolidado, axis=1, join='inner').sort_index()
arq_consolidado.to_csv(r'C:\Users...arq_consolidado.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É porque você definiu `axis=1` na função `pd.concat()`, quando deveria ser `axis=0`, `axis='index'`, ou, ainda, sem especificar o argumento, visto que este é o padrão. Muda isso e resolve o problema :)

E só por curiosidade, dá para criar a lista de arquivos .csv por compreensão também:

```
consolidado = [pd.read_csv(diretorio.format(arquivo)) for arquivo in lista_arquivos]
arq_consolidado = pd.concat(consolidado, join='inner')
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada Cainã eu usei esse de compressão e deu super certo!